# preg_match no valida salto de línea o retorno de carro

Tags: php, validación, preg-match

A ver por favor si alquien me puede echar un cable, no se donde estoy cometiendo el error.
Estoy tratando de validar con preg_match un textarea que me llega mediante un $_POST al controlador y de la siguiente forma trato de validarlo:

```
if( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙüÜ \€\ç\Ç\"\[\]\-\_\*\¿\?\.\,\:\;\(\)\'\{\}\n\r\t]*$/', $datos["datos"])
         ){

        //envio al modelo para grabar el registro

        $respuesta = Modelo::mdlCrearRegistro($datos);

        echo $respuesta; // puede venir ok ó error

    }else{

        echo "caracteres no autorizados";
        
    }
```

Si el textarea no lleva ningún retorno de carro valida correctamente siempre y cuando no lleve por ejemplo el caracter % o el caracter &, vamos en definitiva los que no están definidos en el patrón.

En el caso de que el textArea lleve algún retorno de carro, el preg_match no me valida.

He probado colocando en el patrón \s pero tampoco me funciona. En cuanto coloco en el campo un retorno de carro, no valida.

Si elimino la validación con preg_match "graba bien" el registro en la base de datos y el retorno de carro lo veo en la tabla como \n. Si consulto el registro a través de su CRUD me lo reproduce perfectamente con sus retornos de carro todo perfectamente, tal y como entró en el textarea.

¿Podría eliminar la validación mediante preg_match y a correr? pues si, pero creo que no debo.

A ver si alguien me pudiese orientar donde estoy cometiendo el error. Necesito evidentemente que en el textarea se puedan escribir retornos de carro y que preg_match me los valide al igual que caracteres que quiero que lleguen al servidor para grabar el registro.

Gracias de antemano.

Texto que le envio en el post:

```
Servicios prestados como personal empleado y vinculación temporal en la misma plaza o categoría a la que se desea acceder.
2.- segunda línea
3.- tercera línea
4.- cuarta línea
```

lo que veo en la BBDD si elimino el preg_match

[{"ididioma":"1","titulo":"1.A - Mes completo trabajado","texto":"Servicios prestados como personal empleado y vinculación temporal en la misma plaza o categoría a la que se desea acceder.\n2.- segunda línea\n3.- tercera línea\n4.- cuarta línea"},{"ididioma":"2","titulo":"1.A - Mes complet treballat","texto":"Serveis Prestats com a personal empleat amb vinculació temporal en la mateixa plaça o categoria a la quel es desitja accedir"}]

Comment: A mi si me valida un texto en dos lineas.  ¿puedes poner un ejemplo de lo que no te valida pero debería segun tu?

Comment: Claro que puedo. Ahi va: Servicios prestados como personal empleado y vinculación temporal en la misma plaza o categoría a la que se desea acceder.
2.- segunda linea
3.- tercera linea
4.- cuarta linea

Comment: No lo pongas en el comentario, que justamente no respecta los saltos de linea... ponlo en la pregunta. Para ello pulsa sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta y agrega esa información al final de tu pregunta, gracias

Comment: Vale, disculpa por favor.

Comment: Aunque tu mismo te has respondido y ya lo has solucionado, he de decir que el código de tu pregunta y el texto que has agregado al final me siguen fucionando bien sin tocar nada del patrón del preg_match.  Será alguna otra cosa que te fuerza a poner eso del `\\\\\n` pues aislando el código de tu entorno, en mis pruebas locales, me funciona bien.

Answer (score 0):

Vale creo que lo tengo. Me he dado cuenta al hacer el maldito copia y pega del maldito registro. Dado el formato en el que estoy guardándolo haria falta el caracter escape 3 veces. En lugar \n tendria que ser \\\n. Lo he probado y así funciona. Solo manda el mensaje de caracteres no autorizados cuando escribo algún caracter que no está incluido en el patrón.
Pido disculpas por la posible molestia. Ayer en todo el día me pude dar cuenta, ni se me pasó por la cabeza. Mejor cuando son muchas horas dejarlo sin empecinarse y retomarlo.
Gracias!!